# success message with popup after submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, slim

I have a form that allows you to enter the new songs in the database. The problem is when I click on the button "save" I would like to bring up a popup with the message of successful inclusion. I have two files, one representing the view, and the other controller. Can I put a variable in the controller that contains the JavaScript code that allows me to bring up the popup and then retrieve it from view?

**This is the controller ( i use Slim Framework).**

```
$popup = array();
$popup = '$(function(){
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true, 
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});';
$app->render('newkaraoke.html', array('pop'=>$popup));
```

**this is the view where the reference variable**

```
<?php echo $pop;?>
```

Comment: what you want to do is an ajax call, this can be done with `jQuery.post();` or `jQuery.ajax()`. if you do a little research you can find out how this works

Comment: why are you declaring `$popup` as array and then assigning a string to it?

Comment: Why do you want here to use php to insert js ? Just use a `.js` script.

Answer (score 0):

*My solution does not take any framework into account, but should work regardless.*

The easiest method you could make for this is a simple `if()` statement like so:

```
if(isset(_POST['submit-music'])) {
echo "
    <div id='success-message'>Your song has been added to the database</div>
";
}
```

This code works as long as you pass the `$_POST['submit-music']` variable to the view. You could always put the POST var in something easier like `$submitted` and just check if that exists.

For removing the pop-up (if you want to) I wrote the following code (it uses JQuery however, but you might be able to create a Javascript alternative).

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#success-message').delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

3000 is the amount of time that passes before fading the div out. In this case it's set to 3 seconds.